# python3: bytes vs bytearray, and converting to and from strings

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, utf

I'd like to understand about python3's `bytes` and `bytearray` classes.  I've seen documentation on them, but not a comprehensive description of their differences and how they interact with `string` objects.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## `bytes` and `bytearray` are similar...

##### (TL;DR: bytes are readonly, bytearrays are read-write.)

Python 3's `bytes` and `bytearray` classes both hold arrays of bytes, where each byte can take on a value between 0 and 255.  The primary difference is that a `bytes` object is *immutable*, meaning that once created, you cannot modify its elements.  By contrast, a `bytearray` object allows you to modify its elements.

Both `bytes` and `bytearray` provide functions to encode and decode strings.

### `bytes` and encoding strings

A bytes object can be constructed in a few different ways:

```
>>> bytes(5)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

>>> bytes([116, 117, 118])
b'tuv'

>>> b'tuv'
b'tuv'

>>> bytes('tuv')
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

>>> bytes('tuv', 'utf-8')
b'tuv'

>>> 'tuv'.encode('utf-8')
b'tuv'

>>> 'tuv'.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfet\x00u\x00v\x00'

>>> 'tuv'.encode('utf-16-le')
b't\x00u\x00v\x00'
```

Note the difference between the last two: 'utf-16' specifies a generic utf-16
encoding, so its encoded form includes a two-byte "byte order marker" preamble
of `[0xff, 0xfe]`.  When specifying an explicit ordering of 'utf-16-le' as in
the latter example, the encoded form omits the byte order marker.

Because a bytes object is immutable, attempting to change one of its elements
results in an error:

```
>>> a = bytes('tuv', 'utf-8')
>>> a
b'tuv'
>>> a[0] = 115
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

### `bytearray` and encoding strings

Like `bytes`, a bytearray can be constructed in a number of ways:

```
>>> bytearray(5)
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')

>>> bytearray([116, 117, 118])
bytearray(b'tuv')

>>> bytearray('tuv')
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

>>> bytearray('tuv', 'utf-8')
bytearray(b'tuv')

>>> bytearray('tuv', 'utf-16')
bytearray(b'\xff\xfet\x00u\x00v\x00')

>>> bytearray('abc', 'utf-16-le')
bytearray(b't\x00u\x00v\x00')
```

Because a `bytearray` is *mutable*, you can modify its elements:

```
>>> a = bytearray('tuv', 'utf-8')
>>> a
bytearray(b'tuv')
>>> a[0]=115
>>> a
bytearray(b'suv')
```

### Appending `bytes` and `bytearray`

`bytes` and `bytearray` objects may be catenated with the + operator:

```
>>> a = bytes(3)
>>> a
b'\x00\x00\x00'

>>> b = bytearray(4)
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00')

>>> a+b
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

>>> b+a
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Note that the concatenated result takes on the type of the first argument, so `a+b` produces a `bytes` object and `b+a` produces a `bytearray`.

### Converting `bytes` and `bytearray` objects into strings

`bytes` and `bytearray` objects can be converted to strings using the `decode` function.  The function assumes that you provide the same decoding type as the encoding type.  For example:

```
>>> a = bytes('tuv', 'utf-8')
>>> a
b'tuv'
>>> a.decode('utf-8')
'tuv'

>>> b = bytearray('tuv', 'utf-16-le')
>>> b
bytearray(b't\x00u\x00v\x00')
>>> b.decode('utf-16-le')
'tuv'
```