# Python to MQTT with a Java bytearray

Tags: python, mqtt

I've made a snippet to connect to a remote mqtt server that I do not administrate,
I know the Java message is accepted but the python message isn't. Any idea?
I'm not familiar with python byte stuff.

I do JSON > byte stuff

In Java I can send a message with payload in byte or bytearray
[image]

But in Python, the message is received but the admin report broker error

```
`b'{\n  "subject": "subject1",\n  "date": "Wed, 17 Feb 2021 13:27:32 +0100"\n}'` to topic `testtopic/testchannel`
```

abc being my json.

```
>>> 'abc'.encode('utf-8') b'abc'

>>> bytearray('abc', 'utf-8') bytearray(b'abc')
```

`400 Bad Request: [{"error":"BadRequest","description":"date has invalid format"}]`

[python3: bytes vs bytearray, and converting to and from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903377/python3-bytes-vs-bytearray-and-converting-to-and-from-strings)

Comment: Please do NOT post images of text, they are really hard to read and impossible for people that need to use screen readers.

Comment: Also update the question to show the actual code as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For the code it's default python paho mqtt. I can't get access to the broker's code so there no reproducible example I'm afraid

Comment: No, you need to show us a LOT more of your code, in the context of how it's actually used. What you've supplied tells us nothing about how it's interacting with the Paho code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so obviously, the date error is actually a date type error

The type was enforced.

Conclusion all the payload format are working.